# CI / CD and release management with Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

**Setup**

- Visual Studio 2013
- SCM using Git with bare repositories held on network filesystem
- SourceTree
- Jenkins build server
- Typical projects include c# WinFroms and Web Api/MVC applications
- Each VS solution holds test projects e.g. unit tests / integration tests
- Oracle

**Questions**

*What are the best practices, techniques for a Jenkins/Git setup for a development team?*

So far my plan is to run a Jenkins master on a VM running Windows Server 2012 (I've looked at Docker but for now I'm not using this in our setup).  The agents however, will be installed on the same server.  Why? Thinking ahead there is every chance things like tests will start to take longer as more are added, especially the integration tests.  My reasoning for this approach, is that it would make it easier to move agents out, with little to no work to update all the jobs that are created in the meantime on the master.  This of course is totally based on my own assumptions of how things hang together in Jenkins, so I'm open to feedback on this approach.

Currently the team will pull in the master branch of a repository to work on locally.  Branching off if needed for longer term development, then merging back to master which triggers a build in Jenkins.

As for managing the release versions I'm thinking of adopting this approach. First identify the type of change e.g. major/minor and set the first two parts of the project assemblyinfo.cs accordingly e.g. 2.1.* where * will be replaced/managed by a Jenkins plugin.  As far as I can tell this is the best approach, again open to feedback on this one.

*Are there other open-source tools that I should be using to assist with release management?*

Our build server as it stands today can:

- Trigger builds after a commit to the remote repository
- Run test projects and fail a build if needed

This is where things get tricky as I've seen various approaches to the process/workflow used for releasing a build.  We have no mainstream change management tool in place, other than a dominos database accessible via Lotus Notes used to track and manage change requests.

The hurdle I need to get past is how to effectively control the release management phase.  Is it good practice/permissible to just use pipelines and halt the pipeline with input requests.  In this scenario the developer can choose how far they want to go down in the pipeline e.g. release to UAT or all the way to production.

In previous businesses I've worked at, a release would involve:

- Raising a change ticket (with appropriate approvals in place)
- Packaging up the artefacts that are linked to the ticket
- Release to a UAT staging area based on the linked artefacts
- If the release to UAT is successful then it's possible to schedule an automatic release to live.

I'd like to get something close to what I've described above, but not sure what is out there to achieve my goal with open source software.  So I'm hoping someone in the SO community is in the know!  The last thing I want to do is spend time building a custom tool when something already exists, or even worse, selecting the wrong tool which causes a lot of pain later down the line.

Comment: This question is too general. If you are using GitHub or BitBucket there are really good plugins for Jenkins that handle releases/changelog/Pull Requests. If your source control is more of a git native, support still exists but with less feature set. Regarding the second part of your question, using a input to stop a pipeline is possible and widely used. Especially for the delivery part.

Comment: Thanks Chen.  I'm using Git, the actual open source project available at git-scm.com.  I would have loved to use github/bitbucket but it wasn't on the table for us to use.  The question is broad in the sense of trying to understand best practices which do vary from business to business.  Appreciate your feedback about the pipelines, good to know that others are using it in a similar way that I'm proposing :o).